# Is ∃x∈S(P (x)) shorthand for ∃x(x ∈ S ∧ P (x)) or ∃x(x ∈ S → P (x))?

Tags: function, set, discrete-mathematics, quantifiers, set-theory

In Discrete mathematics and its applications Book

by Kenneth H. Rosen

In chapter 2 setction 2.1(page no 124 in pdf)

"Using Set Notation with Quantifiers

Sometimes we restrict the domain of a quantified statement explicitly by making use of a
particular notation. For example, ∀x∈S(P (x)) denotes the universal quantification of P (x)
over all elements in the set S. In other words, ∀x∈S(P (x)) is shorthand for ∀x(x ∈ S → P (x)).
Similarly, ∃x∈S(P (x)) denotes the existential quantification of P (x) over all elements in S.
That is, ∃x∈S(P (x)) is shorthand for ∃x(x ∈ S ∧ P (x)). "

But isn't ∃x∈S(P (x)) shorthand for ∃x(x ∈ S → P (x)) ?

If it is ∃x∈S(P (x)) shorthand for ∃x(x ∈ S ∧ P (x)),then why? Doesn't '∧'(and) has to br replaced by '→'(impiles that) ?

Comment: The quote [with added note] states: "∀x∈S(P (x)) [which is not the same as ∃x∈S(P (x))] is shorthand for ∀x(x ∈ S → P (x))"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about [math.se] instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 1):

The original description seems to be correct.
The difference is due to the nature of "limiting" the quantified statement to  a smaller set.
I will just rephrase the logic in English:
For universal quantification, you want to say that every element in S satisfies P, in other words, for any x, if x is in S, then x must satisfy P.
For existential quantification, you want to say that there is SOME element in S that satisfies P, in other words, there is some x such that x is in S, AND x satisfies P.

On the other hand, your proposal, `∃x(x ∈ S → P (x))` means something else. It means that there is some x such that "if x is in S, then x satisfies P". In particular, any x outside of S will satisfy the statement.

Eg, take the set `S = {1, 2, 3}` and the condition `P(x) = x > 4`.
Now `∃x∈S(P (x))` should be false because there is no x in S that satisfies P.
And sure enough,  `∃x(x ∈ S ∧ P (x))` is false.
But `∃x(x ∈ S → P (x))` is true because of the number 5. The number 5 is not in S, therefore, it satisfies "if x is in S then x satisfies P".
See the [truth table of implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Truth_table) if this is surprising to you. It's just how "implication" is defined in logic.